# Graphlab Create setup error: graphlab.get_dependencies() results in BadZipFile error

Tags: graphlab

After installing Graphlab Create on Win 10, it asks us to install 2 dependencies using graphlab.get_dependencies().

However, I am getting the following error:

```
    In [9]: gl.get_dependencies()

    By running this function, you agree to the following licenses.

    * libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html
    * xz: http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING

    Downloading xz.
    Extracting xz.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BadZipfile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
    ----> 1 gl.get_dependencies()

    C:\Users\nikulk\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\dependencies.pyc in get_dependencies()
         34     xzarchive_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
         35     print('Extracting xz.')
    ---> 36     xzarchive = zipfile.ZipFile(xzarchive_file)
         37     xzarchive.extractall(xzarchive_dir)
         38     xz = os.path.join(xzarchive_dir, 'bin_x86-64', 'xz.exe')

    C:\Users\nikulk\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\zipfile.pyc in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
        768         try:
        769             if key == 'r':
    --> 770                 self._RealGetContents()
        771             elif key == 'w':
        772                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

    C:\Users\nikulk\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\zipfile.pyc in _RealGetContents(self)
        809             raise BadZipfile("File is not a zip file")
        810         if not endrec:
    --> 811             raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
        812         if self.debug > 1:
        813             print endrec

    BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Anyone knows how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error, a firewall might be blocking you from downloading a dependency. Here is some information and a work around:

Please see the SFrame source code for get_dependencies to see how GraphLab uses this package: https://github.com/turicode/SFrame/blob/master/oss_src/unity/python/sframe/dependencies.py

The xz utility is only used to extract runtime dependencies from the other file downloaded there (from repo.msys2.org): http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-5.1.0-1-any.pkg.tar.xz. **Two DLLs from that file need to be extracted into the "cython" directory inside the GraphLab Create install path (typically something like lib/site-packages/python2.7/graphlab within a virtualenv or conda env). Once extracted the dependency issue should be resolved.**

Answer (score 0):

In graphlab folder make the folder writable.Initially it is only readable.Go to properties of folder undo the only read option.Hope it solve your problem.